# mat-select y evento change

Tags: angular, html-select

estoy tratando de hechar a andar un mat-select, cargo los datos bien, pero quiero hacer algo cuando se seleccione uno de los valores.

Utilizo angular 6, este es mi codigo del ts:

```js
import { Component, Input }                     from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit }                               from '@angular/core';

//---------------------------
// Router
//---------------------------
import { Router }               from '@angular/router';

//---------------------------
// Angular Forms
//---------------------------
import { FormBuilder }          from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup }            from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators }           from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControl }          from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidatorsLibrary }    from '../../../../core/services/validators.service';

import { SecurityService }      from '../../../../services/security.service';
import { GlobalsService }       from '../../../../core/services/globals.service';
import { LogService }           from '../../../../core/services/log.service';
import { UserService }          from '../../../../services/user.service';
import { User }                 from '../../../../models/user.model';
import { Plan }                 from '../../../../models/interfaces/plan.interface';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-comp',
  templateUrl: './select-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-comp.component.css']
})

export class Comp...Component implements OnInit {
    public plans                    : Plan[] = [];
    public promotionalCode          : string;
    public totalSubscription        : number = 0;    
    public _selectPaymentPlanForm   : FormGroup;
    public classButtonColor         : string;
    public selectedPlan             : Plan;

    private routerService   : Router;
    private securityService : SecurityService;
    private globalsService  : GlobalsService;
    private logService      : LogService;
    private userService     : UserService;
    private fb              : FormBuilder;
    private validator       : ValidatorsLibrary;

    constructor(
        fb: FormBuilder,
        rt: Router,
        ss: SecurityService,
        ls: LogService,
        us: UserService,
    ) {
        // Services
        this.securityService    = ss;
        this.routerService      = rt;
        this.logService         = ls;
        this.globalsService     = GlobalsService.getInstance();
        this.userService        = us;
        this.fb                 = fb;

        this.createForm();
        

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.classButtonColor = 'primary';
        this.plans = [
            { id: 1, name: 'abc', price: 40, description: 'desc1...' },
            { id: 2, name: 'qwe', price: 9.95, description: 'desc2...' },
            { id: 3, name: 'asd', price: 19.95, description: 'desc3...' },
        ];
    }

    createForm()
    {
        this._selectPaymentPlanForm  = this.fb.group({

            'plans'                 : ['', Validators.compose([                                      
                                      Validators.required
                                     ])
                                    ],

            'promotionalCode'       : ['', Validators.compose([                                      
                                      Validators.minLength(3)
                                     ])
                                    ],
            'totalSubscription'     : ['', Validators.compose([                                      
                                        Validators.minLength(3)
                                       ])
                                    ],                        


        });
    }

select(plan)
{
    console.log(plan)
}

    
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="_selectPaymentPlanForm" (ngSubmit) = "cmdSelectPaymentPlan_click()" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field class="input-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="Plans" formControlName="plans" (change)="select(plan)"  required>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let plan of plans" [value]="plan.name">
        {{ plan.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br/>
  ...
</form
```

Cuando selecciono un valor del select no ocurre nada...

Answer (score 10):

En lugar de (change) usa (selectionChange)

```
 <form [formGroup]="_selectPaymentPlanForm" (ngSubmit) = "cmdSelectPaymentPlan_click()" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field class="input-width">
        <mat-select placeholder="Plans" formControlName="plans" (selectionChange)="select(plan)"  required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let plan of plans" [value]="plan.name">
              {{ plan.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br/>
    ...
 </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Tenés dos opciones:

### 1. Usar `selectionChange`en la plantilla

Podés usar la directiva de cambio `selectionChange` directamente en el `mat-select` de tu plantilla HTML y usar el objeto `$event` para tomar el valor seleccionado, o sea `(selectionChange)="select($event.value)"`

```
<form [formGroup]="_selectPaymentPlanForm" (ngSubmit)="cmdSelectPaymentPlan_click()" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field class="input-width">
        <mat-select placeholder="Plans" formControlName="plans" (selectionChange)="select($event.value)"  required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let plan of plans" [value]="plan.name">
              {{ plan.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br/>
    ...
</form>
```

### 2. Usar `valueChange` en el modal

La otra opcion es usar `valueChange` en tu objeto `_selectPaymentPlanForm` de tu modal (no en tu HTML)'. `valueChange` te devuelve un Observable desde el cual te poés subcribir a los cambios de una forma o de un control. En este caso necesitamos el cambio del control `plans`.

```
createForm() {
    this._selectPaymentPlanForm  = this.fb.group({
       'plans'                 : ['', Validators.compose([                                      
                                  Validators.required
                                 ])
                                ],
       // ... el resto de los controles                    
    });

    this._selectPaymentPlanForm.get('plans')              // Tomamos el control 'plans'
       .valueChanges.subscribe( valor => select(valor) ); // Subscribimos a los cambios
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola hace rato resolvi este problema de la siguiente manera:

Adicione un evento tipo click en el mat-option, asi cuando se le de click a cualquier option tendre el id o el valor de la misma.

```
 <mat-option (click)="functionName(somevar) [value]="valueVar">
```

En el ts se captura el valor en la funcion "functionName" y listo.